# With respect to creating circles, what are the pros and cons of the following methods?

Tags: gui-design, html, css, javascript, animation

I am making a website in which the home page will have 5 circles each linking to a category of items (e.g. cities, phones, etc.). The user will click on circle to go to the specific page for that item. These 5 circles are arranged equidistantly on the circumference of a bigger circle

[image]

I can think of the following methods to make it, with pros and cons I can think of, but not sure whether my experience is enough to choose the correct option:

A) Create a circle graphics. Place it properly with some programming in CSS on the page.
B) Program everything including circles and their position. Potentially animate them with better effects.

Pros of A) Relatively easy code for others who might join development

Cons of A) Animation and adding other features might need other images, slowing the load time

Pros of B) Easier to add animation and other features with less graphics and load times.

Cons of B) Harder to read and maintain.

Some Example of Animation which I found might be interesting is this:
What pros and cons or other methods do you suggest? while I aim to learn whatever method is best, I believe simplicity and elegance is a highly desired goal.

Comment: I don't believe that this is a UX question. You've already determined what you want the User Experience to be, what you're asking here is *how* to implement it effectively / efficiently. Implementation questions aren't on topic for this site, i'm afraid.

Comment: Simple enough to do with plain CSS (border radius)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Can you advise where implementation questions are posted?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the which browsers and and their versions you need to support, consider using svg elements. They're not too bad in weight, easier to animate (e.g. with Adobe Edge) and adapt to well to different screen sizes.

Comment: Thanks so much. I would be using only freeware though. If I go the SVG way what is a good freeware animation tool?

Comment: You would be limited but you can use Adobe Edge's trial version.